# Get single-digit number after fixed string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following string,

```
something id-4 something
```

What is the js regex for returning the "4"?

Closest I've got was

```
[id-][0-9]{1}
```

But it returns "-4" not "4".

Comment: In which implementation? Perl/GNU/Python/VB/JavaScript .....

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the character class construct for the prefix, just do this:

```
id-[0-9]{1}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're looking for js regex, have a try with:

```
s='something id-4 something';
re = /id-(\d)/;
m = re.exec(s);
// m[1] contains "4"
```